# How can I delete/release resources of a Task from UI?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task

From UI, I create some `Task`, such as:

```
Task taskCancellaCartellaDestinazione = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CancellaCartellaDestinazione(), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
taskCancellaCartellaDestinazione.ContinueWith(t => TaskGestioneCartelle(), CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

each `Task` has its own variable name, so I can access to it directly. How can I stop and release resource of them?

Such as if I click on a stop `Button`, the threads must be stopped.

On `taskCancellaCartellaDestinazione` I don't see any `Abort()` or `Cancel()` functions.

Comment: I'm not sure if Task is the best option here. Have you tried BackgroundWorker which supports cancellation?

Comment: I don't know what `BackgroundWorker` are.

Comment: Please check out this quick example I wrote: http://pastebin.com/69MDnKx5 To cancel it, you just invoke CancelAsync() on your worker.

Comment: @PiotrJustyna Note that calling `CancelAsync` won't do anything unless the `DoWork` method periodically checks for cancellation.

Comment: @Servy True. I don't intend to force any cancellation mechanism on the OP though. Just showing an alternative to the Task.

Comment: @PiotrJustyna Well, both mechanisms are *very* similar.  Neither is radically different.  Both the BGW and tasks have a similar level of support for cancellation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a `CancellationTokenSource` just before you start the task.
2. Pass the `CancellationToken` from the token source to `CancellaCartellaDestinazione`.
3. In the body of `CancellaCartellaDestinazione` periodically check if the cancellation token has requested cancellation, in most cases calling `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is appropriate.
4. Pass that cancellation token to `StartNew` instead of `CancellationToken.None`.
5. When you want to cancel the task, call `Cancel` on the `CancellationTokenSource`.

Comment: Oh well, now I got what you mean! Can I use `var ts = new CancellationTokenSource();` for all Thread if I want to stop them all so?

Comment: @markzzz I'm not sure what there is to not understand.  You litter the code with `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` at various points in which you want to allow the task to be canceled.  Make sure to pass it on to any long running sub-tasks that are started.  In most cases if you have a loop that does most of the work, calling it once in that loop should suffice.  The whole point is that when you call `Cancel` it won't actually stop the task until you next reach a call to `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

Comment: @markzzz Sure.  You can use a single source if you know that they will all be cancelled together.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `ct.IsCancellationRequested`. Just I'd like to know if I can use the same token for each thread!